# Combining Two WiFi Networks While Each Having Their Own Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, bridge

I have two wifi routers in my home. And two ISP connections. ISP1 is connected to router 1 and ISP2 is connected to router 2. Both routers are in DHCP mode. I have a plex server running on an old i3 CPU and a raspberry pi acting as a cups server. Both of them are connected to router 1. Router 1 has 40Mbps internet and router 2 has 15Mbps internet. What I want to achieve is to be able to access the LAN devices of router 1 when I am connected to router 2. When I am connected to router 2, I should still be able to access my plex server but when I, for example, surf the internet I should consume data from router 2 instead of router 1. Is this possible?

I've found, after a while of search, a similar question on tom's hardware but I am not sure how to set it up.

Link--> https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/dual-wan-two-isps-and-combining-the-two-network-segments.3514085/

Comment: If you can connect the Plex server to router 2 you could eliminate the usage of router 1 entirely - Plex data streaming to the LAN devices doesnt use Internet bandwidth, only LAN bandwidth, and if the router's good enough you can stream Plex and still have bandwidth to use the 40 Mbps line without much lagging. You can also (based on router's 1 flexibility and configuration) connect router 1 directly TO router 2 and not use the router 1 15Mbps line at all. Some vendor specific routers cant do this but an aftermarket (such as Netgear) one can do this very well

Comment: What router models do you have? How many Ethernet ports does the Plex server have?

Comment: @user1686 Both are vendor specific routers. However, I can change all settings and modify route tables too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your gateway ips within the same 192.168 (or 10.10 whatever)and your subnet 255.255.0.0.  An example:  Router 1 (Gateway 1) 192.168.0.1  and router 2 192.168.1.1.  A subnet of 255.255.255.0 would not allow the networks to communicate but a subnet of 255.255.0.0 will.

Comment: Should I connect the two routers via a LAN cable? Any extra config to be done on the routers?

Comment: No. That would defeat the purpose of having two distinct intranets, and could cause looping issues.  Running just one network might simplify things, or use one as a backup.  If you are out of ethernet ports you can always get a cheap dumb switch.

Comment: Then how do both routers communicate with each other if they are not connected over LAN?

Comment: If none of your devices are connected to both networks you could connect both routers to a dumb hub or switch.  You could connect them directly with a crossover cable but that might cause problems.  Whenever I have set up two networks there was always a minimum of 20 devices so hubs and switches were always part of the mix.  If you have fewer devices and are determined to run two networks you can still get a GBE five port hub for $15.

Comment: Keep in mind the two networks do not need any special set up, beyond changing the subnet from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0.  A subnet of 255.255.255.0 only allows devices on the same 192.168.0.* OR 192.168.1.* networks to 'talk'.  255.255.0.0 allows ALL 192.168.*.*  (connected) devices to 'talk'.

Comment: Please excuse me, I am a total noob in networking. What will be the subnet if the LAN IP of one router is 10.0.0.1 and other is 192.168.55.1 ?

Comment: 0.0.0.0, but that will not work too well with over 4 Billion possible addresses.  255.255.255.0 keeps that number at 254, 255.255.0.0 has 65,000 possible addresses.  The gateways will have to be somewhat similar pairs of private ip addresses like 10.0.x.x or 192.168.x.x or even 172.16.x.x and will all work (but not with each other) with multiple networks and a 255.255.0.0 subnet.

Comment: Thanks. I almost got it to work. In router A is used the gateway IP : 10.0.0.1 and in router B is used the gateway IP: 10.0.1.0. Since I do not have a dumb ethernet switch, I just connected the two routers using a LAN cable. I get internet access in my ubuntu laptop. However, when I connect my android to router A I get the IP of router B. For example, the IP of my android should be 10.0.0.45 when connected to router A, but it gets the 10.0.1.102, which belongs to the router B. What am I doing wrong?

I only changed the gateway IP and the subnet in both routers. No other changes.

Comment: You need either a hub or a crossover cable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) between the routers.

Comment: Sorry. I thought both crossover and ethernet cable are the same.

Comment: Almost, crossover cables switch the 1 with 3 and the 2 with 6 wires (send and receive pairs)

Comment: You mean, one end it is like the regular cable but at the other end, it is reversed right?